# Another color is binding color in Cardview?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-mvvm, android-binder

Hello I am trying set a red color in `app:cardBackgroundColor` on a `CardView` for do this I have the following code:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/cvPassword"
                    style="@style/card_view.with_elevation.edit_text"
           app:cardBackgroundColor="@{registerViewModel.passwordCvColor}"
                    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/checkBox"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guidelineRegisterEnd"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guidelineRegisterStart"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cvRepeatEmail">
```

In the ViewModel I have the following code:

```
public final MutableLiveData<Integer> passwordCvColor = new MutableLiveData<>();
```

And for change the color I have the following code:

```
  binding.setPasswordHandler(new Handler(){
            @Override
            public void onFocusLost() {
                String password = registerViewModel.email.getValue();
                if(password == null || password.isEmpty()){
                    registerViewModel.passwordCvColor.setValue(R.color.red);
                }else{
                    registerViewModel.passwordCvColor.setValue(null);
                }
            }
        });
```

This "work" because the observer changes the value to R.color.red the color is changed in the view, but the new color is dark blue instead of red.

I am trying to set directly the color in the layout, and this work and the color is red, but with the ViewModel doesn't.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Don't know if it's the case and can't test it right now, but sometimes you need to call getColor() instead of passing directly the id

Comment: This work finally with `ContextCompat.getColor(RegisterActivity.this, R.color.red)`, if you want create a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're passing directly the id in `registerViewModel.passwordCvColor.setValue(R.color.red);` the color will be the reference to the color resource in the [R file](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R) and not the color itself, something like `0x7f010000` and that hardly will be the color you want.

You should call a method to get the resource using this id instead.
In the older versions you could use `getResources().getColor()` but as it is deprecated now you should use `ContextCompat.getColor()`.

The code will look like this:

```
registerViewModel.passwordCvColor.setValue(ContextCompat.getColor(RegisterActivity.this, R.color.red));
```